# Reading file form classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a maven project and want to read file in it form its class path. The code that i am using is

`InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream ("filename.json");`

But every time i am getting `null` inputstreams. I am not sure why ?

The file is places under `/src/main/resources`. The same folder which contains `log4j.xml` and it is being picked up decently.

Please note, I am trying to run this file from Eclipse i.e., run or debug mode. No vm arguments or whatsoever.

Comment: What does the javadoc of `getResourceAsStream` say? What does the javadoc of `getResource` say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Class.getResourceAsStream(String)` method looks for the given resource within the same namespace (i.e. package) that the given class is in unless you give it an absolute path (see [the API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-)); If it can't find the resource on the classpath in this namespace, it returns `null`. Since your class is likely inside e.g. `com.myproject.resourcemanagement`, your resource file has to analogously be under `src/main/resources/com/myproject/resourcemanagement`, similary to how your class source files are organised (under `src/main/java/com/myproject/resourcemanagement`).

Comment: hmm. I am getting more confused after reading the documentation. so lets say the output of my project is a .jar file and i have a file one.json at the same folder where .jar file is located. I want to read one.json file inside the class which is part of that .jar, how would i do that ?

Comment: To avoid this, you can use `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()` which is more straightforward, imo. You can put your resource anywhere on the classpath (of that class loader), e.g. on the root of the jar.

Comment: Then you're using the wrong tool, because this file most likely isn't on your classpath (it won't be automatically configured that way by Maven, anyway); Just use [some normal file I/O instead](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-).